# Cassandra Datastax Driver with Squirrel SQL

Tags: cassandra, squirrel-sql

I'm trying to use the Datastax driver cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar with the Squirrel SQL client.

The problem is that I don't know what to put in the class name field. Does anyone know? Or does anyone know how I would figure it out?

I think it's probably something like `com.datastax.driver.core.___` but I can't get that last piece.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that you can.  I think the Datastax driver allows connections from Java but is not JDBC compliant, as there is no class in the `com.datastax.driver.core` package that implements `java.sql.Driver`.  If there were, this would be the class to use in SQuirreL.